# A metric characterization of Hilbert spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, ho.history-overview

In the [Wikipedia paper on Hadamard spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_space), it is written that every flat Hadamard space is isometric to a closed convex subset of a Hilbert space. Looking through references provided by this Wikipedia paper, I found that this fact is proved as Theorem 7.2 in [the lecture notes of Jacob Lurie](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/hadamard.pdf). Since those notes contain no references and no historical information, it is not clear:

> To whom this important result should be attributed? And when it was proved for the first time?

**Remark.**  I am asking this question because, the mentioned Theorem 7.2 in Lurie notes implies the following nice characterization of metric spaces, which are isometric to Hilbert spaces:

> **Theorem.** A metric space $(X,d)$ is isometric to a Hilbert space if and only if it is nonempty, complete, and satisfies the following two (first-order) conditions:
>
> 1. $\forall x,y\in X\;\exists z\in X\;\; \big[d(x,z)=d(x,y)+d(y,z)=2d(x,y)\big]$;
> 2. $\forall x,y\in X\;\exists m\in X\;\forall z\in X\;\big[d(z,m)^2=\tfrac12d(x,z)^2+\tfrac12d(y,z)^2-\tfrac 14d(x,y)^2\big]$.

I hope that this characterization is known (to the specialists). So the question is *to whom should it be attributed*?

> *Is this theorem the simplest (in a reasonable sense) metric characterization of Hilbert spaces?*

Comment: Another metric characterization of flat Hadamard spaces can be found in exercise 0.0.2 on p.3 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.03483.pdf. Namely, a complete length space $X$ is isometric to a convex subset of a Hilbert space if and only if every 4-point-quadruple in $X$ admits an isometric embedding into a Euclidean space. Is it simpler?

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thank you for the comment and link to the book (very interesting) but try to write down this characterization as a (desirably first-order) property of the metric, I am not sure that it will be so short.